# Catching a python submodule import error that's resolved by the test harness?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Given the following (broken) python snippet:

```
import a
def myfunction():
   a.b.hello()
```

As expected, this function fails when called because of the missing submodule.

However, if you had code in any other module that did `import a.b` (for other reasons), this function would then run without error.

This can be a real problem if the submodule import is in a test harness, because the test harness effectively masks the problem.

How would you best catch or prevent such a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this would fail (unconditionally). There is an object of some kind `b` inside the module `a` which has a callable called `hello`. That's quite possible. Why do you say "as expected, this function fails".

Comment: "import a.b" would make it work. But at least on my machine (python 2.7 on a mac) "import a" doesn't.  Here's a short example https://github.com/nilsbunger/python-submodule-import-error  Just grab the code and run `python main.py`  . It should fail.  Then run `python test.py`, and it will succeed. The error is masked!

Comment: I just improved the example...

Comment: This is because your `__init__.py` inside the package `a` doesn't import `b`. I'm not sure how to avoid the masking problem you've mentioned in your test (short of actually going to `sys.modules` inside your test and deleting the entry for `a`).