# Django Test shows import error but project runs successfully via runserver

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

I have a django project with few apps. The project is running successfully without any error. Now I am writing test cases for some of the apps in the project.

I ran the test using following command

```
 python manage.py test apps.UserProfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import. Your stack trace shows Student depends on Student through a bunch of other modules.

Usually you can solve this by changing your import statement to not have a "from"

Eg import apps.x.y.z

This form of import doesn't actually execute the imported module when it hits that statement, so it doesn't get stuck in a circular import loop.

Comment: There was a circular import through other modules. Its strange that runserver doesn't show any error but running test cases show. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I was wondering about that too. I suspect that the import order is affecting the behavior, but it's not obvious where.  I had a similarly vexing python import issue related to testing which I asked about, but haven't gotten an answer.  Would love if you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914129/catching-a-python-submodule-import-error-thats-resolved-by-the-test-harness